# ASP.NET Web API Posted value not automatically map to object

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send my request with json content to web api, bit these value isn't automatically map to my object.

This is My API Action that result in null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCustomerByName([FromBody] Request_GetCustomerByName request)
    {
        // Some Action
    }
```

If I change parameter like below I can receive my data fine. So I wonder why my json string not automatically map to object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCustomerByName([FromBody] dynamic request)
    {
        // Some action
    }
```

This is where I send my request .

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:40175/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Request_GetCustomerByName r = new Request_GetCustomerByName()
            {
                Customer = new Customer() { CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "Name" },
                RequestBase = new RequestBase() { Somefield="123"}
            };

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(r);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values/GetCustomerByName", json).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resVal = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Response.Write(resVal);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks, I've been stuck at this point for some hour...

Comment: Not much to go on.  Can you post both the definition of the `Request_GetCustomerByName` class an a sample of the JSON that's being sent?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably inspect the Json string, this online json to c# object mapper might help: http://json2csharp.com/.